# Check user's password on LDAP from JAVA application

Tags: java, ldap, wso2-identity-server

I've never used LDAP. I have to write a JAVA class which check if the password given by the user is correct. Users/password are stored in the LDAP server of WSO2IS. This is the configuration:

```
<UserManager>
<Realm>
    <Configuration>
    <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>admin</UserName>
                 <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        <Property name="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.CommonLDAPRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
    </Configuration>

<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:10389</Property>
        <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                       
        <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=admin,ou=system</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin</Property>
        <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
    <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">ou=SharedGroups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(objectClass=organizationalUnit)</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
        <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>

    <AuthorizationManager
        class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
    <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
</Realm>
```

Can you please help me?. I've no idea where to start. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know WSO2IS but it looks like this configuration is already doing that for you.

Comment: WSO2IS has an embedded LDAP which has this configuration. My question is: which APIs should I use to access it inside a JAVA application? Thank you

Comment: Try [this](http://directory.apache.org/api/java-api.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the user/password of the users using some authentication API. There is Web service service called `RemoteUserStoreManagerService` that you can use to verify user/password of the user. Also this API can be used to manage the users in the LDAP.  You can add/update/delete LDAP users. More details about the API can be found from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/) with simple java client to invoke this API